# Grap substring from filenames

Tags: powershell

I have a list of filenames:

```
No. 01 --- SOME NAME VARIABLE LENGTH---1214353.54343 Some more stuff.xlsx
```

All are of a similar format. What I need is to end up with is:

```
1214353.54343
```

That is:

1. everything after the last "---"
2. unto the first [space]

How can I do this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `regex` to grap the string:

```
.*---([\S]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jN5wO2/1).

**PowerShell code:**

```
$fileName = "No. 01 --- SOME NAME VARIABLE LENGTH---1214353.54343 Some more stuff.xlsx"
[regex]::Match($fileName, '.*---([\S]+)').Groups[1].Value
```

**Output:**

```
1214353.54343
```

---

**Edit to your comment:**

```
Get-ChildItem 'your_directory' -Recurse | foreach {
    if ($_.BaseName -match '.*---([\S]+)')
    {
        $Matches[1]
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a cannot index into a null array-error. Could it have something to do wtih the filename in reality being `No. 01---SOME NAME VARIABLE LENGTH---1214353.54343 Some more stuff.xlsx` (notice there are no [spaces] before or after `---` - my mistake, sorry!

Comment: No, if you copy my powershell code and just replace the string it will work. It probably has something to do with the way you are passing the filenames. Can you share that part?

Comment: I'm iterating through a folder and use `[regex]::Match($_.BaseName, '.*---([\S]+)').Groups[1].Value`

Comment: Same error. Annoying and I'm sure my fault. Let me check what I'm missing here...

Comment: Just edit your answer and share the whole code with us, im sure we can help you.

Comment: I have checked. I literally have this: `$filename = "No 01---MY COMPANY WEBSITE---1213232.0521 Current articles.xlsx" write-output [regex]::Match($filename, '.*---([\s]+)').Groups[1].Value` and it is throwing the same error?

Comment: You have to wrap the match if you want to use it in write-output: `Write-Output $([regex]::Match($filename, '.*---([\S]+)').Groups[1].Value)` Also you need a capitalized `S`, not `s`....